# Login verification and Password recovery with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm working on a web app and I wanna try using `JWT` for my user authentication and password recovery. I need `JWT` to verify the valid user from my DB. I tried this:

**login.js**:

```
var User        = require("../model/user/registerSchema").User;
var bcrypt      = require('bcrypt');
var utils       = require('../util/util'),
    config      = require('../config'),
    jwt         = require('jsonwebtoken');

/* Login Route. */

route = (app)=>{

    //POST
    app.post ('/login', (req, res) => {
        let {userName, password} = req.body;

        if (!utils.noEmptyParams(req.body)) res.json({success: false, message: config.messages.NO_DATA});

        else
            User.findOne({userName, password}, {password: 0})
                .exec()
                .then(user => {
                    if (user) {
                        user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));
                        jwt.sign(user, config.jwt.secret, config.jwt.options, (err, token) => {
                            res.json({
                                success: true,
                                user,
                                token,
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.json({success: false, message: config.messages.INVALID_CREDENTIALS});
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    utils.error(error);
                    res.json({success: false});
                });


    });
}

module.exports.route = route;
```

**registerSchema.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        db   = global.db,
    bcrypt   = require('bcrypt');
    var User = new mongoose.Schema();


// MONGOOSE MODEL CONFIGURATION
const RegisterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    access:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, 'please select proffession']
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a username'],
        unique: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your firstname']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add your last name']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a password']
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an email address'],
        unique: true
    },
    companyName: {
        type: String        
    },
});

    RegisterSchema.pre('save', function(next){
        var user = this;
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
            if(err){
                return next(err);
            }
            user.password= hash;
            next()
        })
    })


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', RegisterSchema);
```

I am running on Node version: v9.4.0, I'm using postman to test. When I try posting the require fields,

```
{

    "userName":       "njksdnf@fds.com",
    "password":       "1234567"
}
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at app.post (/home/user/Home/Node/Routers/login.js:19:18)
```

I have seen [WT-user-authentication-API-bolilerplate](https://github.com/alexcambose/JWT-user-authentication-API-bolilerplate)
, but it doesn't seem to help fully.

Any idea on how I can resolve it and how `JWT` can be used in this case for password recovery?

Comment: What seems weird is that the stack trace talks about the file called `login.js` and you giving us the content of `Login.js`, is this a typo ?

Comment: And also, I don't see the export of the `User` model in the `registerSchema.js`, can you show us ?

Comment: thanks @Striped for that observation, it was a typo mistake. And in the `registerSchema` I exported the `User` model `module.exports = mongoose.model('User', RegisterSchema);`

Comment: So it might come from this. In the `login.js` try `var User        = require("../model/user/registerSchema");`.

Comment: Trust me, you did the magic! It worked!!! @Striped

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
    at app.post (/home/user/Home/Node/Routers/login.js:19:18)
```

gotten from postman, all thanks to Striped in the comment. removing the`.User` did the whole magic for me.

Making my code to now be:

```
var User        = require("../model/user/registerSchema");
```

instead of:

```
var User        = require("../model/user/registerSchema").User;
```

Still left with the question "Any idea on how `JWT` can be used in this case for password recovery?